# Find out HTML Object

Tags: html, object

How can i find out that darknetUrl?? All other URLs are already defined in the .html

Thanks for your help

Edit: Thats the whole HTML file cutted in half should be enough i hope... if not i can add the other half also. Maybe also the obj is serversided i dont know i am not familiar with HTML at all.

Thank you again!

```
<div id="site"></div>
<script src="libs/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Array.prototype.contains = function (value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] === value) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    };

    var activeDownload = false;
    var downloadItem = "";
    var darknetUrl;

    function initialize(obj) {
        darknetUrl = obj.darknetUrl;

        $("#lblGo").text(obj.goLabel);
        $("#lblHome").text(obj.homeLabel);
        $("#lblFavorites").text(obj.favoritesLabel);
        $("#lblDownloads").text(obj.downloadsLabel);
        $("#lblClose").text(obj.closeLabel);
    }

    function downloadEventResult(obj) {
        switch (obj.tool) {
            case "hashcat":
                if (obj.state === true) {
                    downloadEvent("Hashcat");
                } else {
                    createModal("Download fehlgeschlagen", "Download konnte nicht ausgeführt werden. Du benötigst ein Speichermedium und genügend Geld auf deinem Konto, um die Software herunter zu laden.");
                    activeDownload = false;
                }
                break;
            case "atmkit":
                if (obj.state === true) {
                    downloadEvent("ATMKit");
                } else {
                    createModal("Download fehlgeschlagen", "Download konnte nicht ausgeführt werden. Du benötigst ein Speichermedium und genügend Geld auf deinem Konto, um die Software herunter zu laden.");
                    activeDownload = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                createModal("Download fehlgeschlagen", "Download konnte nicht ausgeführt werden. Ein unbekannter Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
                activeDownload = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    function downloadFinishedEvent(obj) {
        if (obj.state === true) {
            createModal("Download erfolgreich", "Du hast erfolgreich die Software heruntergeladen.");
        } else {
            createModal("Download fehlgeschlagen", "Download konnte nicht ausgeführt werden. Ein unbekannter Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
        }
    }

    function downloadEvent(itemname) {
        $('.progressDl').css('width', 0 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0);
        $("#downloadDiv").show("slow");
        $("#downloadText").text(itemname);
        setTimeout(downloadTick, 2000, 0);
    }

    function downloadTick(percent) {
        percent += 1;
        $('.progressDl').css('width', percent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percent);
        if (percent === 100) {
            $("#downloadDiv").hide("slow");
            activeDownload = false;
            resourceCall("sendServerEvent", "webBrowserCommand", `{ "action": "downloadFinished", "tool": "${downloadItem}" }`);
        } else {
            setTimeout(downloadTick, 2000, percent);
        }
    }

    function createModal(header, text) {
        $("#modalHeader").text(header);
        $("#modalText").text(text);
        $('#modalInfo').modal('show');
    }

    function switchSite(site) {
        $("#site div").empty();
        resourceCall("sendServerEvent", "webBrowserCommand", `{ "action": "openedWebsite", "website": "${site}" }`);
        switch (site) {
            case "www.test.com":
                $("#site").load("web/Default.html");
                break;
            case "www.bawsaq.com":
                $("#site").load("web/bawsaq.html");
                break;
            case "www.jobs.com":
                $("#site").load("web/jobs.html");
                break;
            case "www.immoscout.com":
                $("#site").load("web/Immoscout.html");
                break;
            case "www.autoscout.com":
                $("#site").load("web/Autoscout.html");
                break;
            case "www.markt.com":
                $("#site").load("web/Markt.html");
                break;
            case "www.police.com":
                $("#site").load("web/LSPD.html");
                break;
            case "www.lifeinvader.com":
                $("#site").load("web/Lifeinvader.html");
                break;
            case darknetUrl:
                $("#site").load("web/Darknet.html");
                break;
            default:
                $("#site").load("web/404.html");
                break;
        }
    }

    function progressWebSearch(percent, website) {
        if (percent === 100) {
            $("#search_form").val(website);
            percent = 0;
            switchSite(website);
            $("#search_form").css('background-size', percent + "%");
        } else {
            percent += 5;
            $("#search_form").css('background-size', percent + "%");
            setTimeout(progressWebSearch, 50, percent, website);
        }
    }

    function setGpsPos(pos) {
        resourceCall(`setGpsNavPoint('${pos}')`);
        createModal("Navigationspunkt gesetzt", "Der Navigationspunkt wurde auf deinem Handy erfolgreich gesetzt");
    }

    $(document).on('click', "#searchWeb", function () {
        website = $("#search_form").val();
        setTimeout(progressWebSearch, 0, 0, website);
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#switchHome", function () {
        setTimeout(progressWebSearch, 0, 0, "www.kweb.kw");
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#fMaze", function () {
        setTimeout(progressWebSearch, 0, 0, "www.mazebank.kw");
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(progressWebSearch, 0, 0, "www.kweb.kw");
        //$("#site").load("web/LSPD.html");
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#closeMenu", function () {
        resourceCall("closeModalBrowser");
    });

    resourceCall('modalBrowserReady');
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds like you already have it stored in your variable `darknetUrl`. Assuming you don't, you'll need to provide the contents of `obj`. I take it you get back a response of `[Object HTMLObject]`? In that case you'll need to share your HTML as well.

Comment: Thanks for you answer is edited the main post

Comment: where can i find the contents of obj ???